# Celery task retry after soft time limit exceeds when late acknowledgement is enabled

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a task that runs for around two minutes doing some DB operation. I enabled the late acknowledgment but I found that the task never retried after the soft time limit exceeded.

So I added [autoretry_for and retry_backoof](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) as mentioned in the documentation of the celery version I'm using. Doing retry for the late acknowledged task is a good practice or not?

If I did not set the `autoretry_for` then the task won't run from where it is terminated.

**tasks.py**

```py
@shared_task(soft_time_limit=20, autoretry_for=(SoftTimeLimitExceeded, ), retry_backoff=True)
def test_func_celery(current_time):
    fake = Faker()
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    time1 = time.perf_counter()
    main_time_end = current_time + 25
    logger.info('Task started here \n \n')

    while time.time() < main_time_end:
        logger.info('Before doing main operations')
        time.sleep(10)
        logger.info(f'Inside Main operation ===>>> {time.time()}')

        while True:
            name = fake.first_name()
            logger.info(f'Inside inner operation for {name}')
            logger.info(f'inner operation before starts for {name}')
            time.sleep(12)
            logger.info(f'Inside inner {name}===>>> {time.time()}')
            logger.info(f'inner operation after finishes for {name}')
            break
        logger.info('Completed Main operation')
        break

    if time.time() >= main_time_end:
        logger.info('Out from main operations')
    time2 = time.perf_counter()
    logger.info(f'Total time =======>>>>>>> {time2 - time1}')
    return None
```

**views.py**

```py
def home(request):
    current_time = time.time()
    test_func_celery.apply_async(args=(current_time, ), acks_late=True)
    return HttpResponse("Celery being tested here")
```

**celery.log**

```
[2020-01-21 15:28:30,708: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task started here 
 

[2020-01-21 15:28:30,708: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Before doing main operations
[2020-01-21 15:28:40,715: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Inside Main operation ===>>> 1579599820.7153742
[2020-01-21 15:28:40,716: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Inside inner operation for Joe
[2020-01-21 15:28:40,716: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] inner operation before starts for Joe
[2020-01-21 15:28:50,680: WARNING/MainProcess] Soft time limit (20s) exceeded for home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4]
[2020-01-21 15:28:50,726: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4]  ETA:[2020-01-21 15:28:51.683861+05:45] 
[2020-01-21 15:28:50,728: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4] retry: Retry in 1s: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
[2020-01-21 15:28:51,938: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task started here 
 

[2020-01-21 15:28:51,938: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Before doing main operations
[2020-01-21 15:29:01,948: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Inside Main operation ===>>> 1579599841.948412
[2020-01-21 15:29:01,949: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Inside inner operation for Lisa
[2020-01-21 15:29:01,949: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] inner operation before starts for Lisa
[2020-01-21 15:29:11,915: WARNING/MainProcess] Soft time limit (20s) exceeded for home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4]
[2020-01-21 15:29:11,965: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4]  ETA:[2020-01-21 15:29:12.917995+05:45] 
[2020-01-21 15:29:11,967: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4] retry: Retry in 1s: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
[2020-01-21 15:29:13,136: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task started here 
 

[2020-01-21 15:29:13,136: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Out from main operations
[2020-01-21 15:29:13,136: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Total time =======>>>>>>> 0.00026752900157589465
[2020-01-21 15:29:13,138: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task home.tasks.test_func_celery[4234d05e-672e-4565-bdb6-cd3d234c82c4] succeeded in 0.05194566200225381s: None
```

Is there any better solution to describe the scenario explained above? It would be a really great help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Setting retry_backoff to False causes a task to run immediately after an exception. When tasks depend on external servers or network, it's recommended to set retry_backoff to True to wait for any network issues to resolve before retrying the task. If the task does not have external dependencies, setting retry_backoff to True is not necessary.